# tkinter unkown error with window updating

Tags: python, tkinter

i wrote a simple program in tkinter to remind me for medicines every fixed interval of time, and when the alarm rings a snooze button should appear which should set the timer to 10 minutes and after that alarm should ring again and if stop is pressed instead of snooze this time it should reset the timer to initially given fixed interval of time.
i don't understand why the snooze button never appears after alarm plays
here's the code :-

```
import tkinter as tk
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import time
stop = False
def start_alarm():
    global interval
    interval = int(entry.get())  # get the interval from the user
    time_left.config(text=str(interval) + " seconds left")
    countdown()

def stop_alarm():
    global stop
    stop = True
    sd.stop()
    start_alarm()

def snooze_alarm():
    global stop
    stop = True
    sd.stop()
    interval += 600
    time_left.config(text=str(interval) + " seconds left")
    countdown()
    
def countdown():
    global interval
    global stop
    if interval > 0 and not stop:
        interval -= 1
        time_left.config(text=str(interval) + "    seconds left")
        time_left.after(1000, countdown)
    elif not stop:
        play_alarm()

def play_alarm():
    data, fs = sf.read('alarm.wav', dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data, fs)
    status = sd.wait()
    create_snooze_button()

def create_snooze_button():
    global snooze_button
    snooze_button = tk.Button(root, text="Snooze", command=snooze_alarm)
    snooze_button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Medicine Reminder")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter time interval (in seconds):")
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_alarm)
start_button.pack()

stop_button = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=stop_alarm)
stop_button.pack()

time_left = tk.Label(root, text="")
time_left.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I don't see `threading` or `Thread` anywhere in this code. What makes you think this is a threading-related issue? Also, if you are seeing specific errors, please include the traceback message in the body of your question! You're also importing the `time` module, but aren't using it anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Btw `tkinter` doesn't always play nice with threads. So avoid calling `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk`

Comment: You'll want to add `global interval` to `snooze_alarm()` as well, since you're modifying its value in that function. And at a guess, it's possible that `status = sd.wait()` is blocking, so `create_snooze_button()` isn't called until the alarm sound stops? That said, I'm not familiar with the `sounddevice` module so I can't be certain.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize for the oversight. In the updated code, I forgot to include the global keyword in the snooze_alarm function before modifying the interval variable.

Comment: i looked at the sd.wait part and tried to update the function to
```def play_alarm():
    global snooze_button
    snooze_button = None
    create_snooze_button()
    data, fs = sf.read('alarm.wav', dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data, fs, blocking=False)```
but now pressing snooze button breaks the timer

Comment: `snooze_alarm()` sets `stop` to `True` just before the call to `countdown`, so `if interval > 0 and not stop` fails. I don't think you need `global stop` or `stop = True` inside `snooze_alarm()`